# Como listar post de outros sites wordpress em um site wordpress em outra hospedagem?

Tags: php, wordpress, back-end

preciso listar os dois últimos posts de um outro site Wordpress que se encontra em outro servidor. Tenho acesso ao Servidor deste outro site que desejo pegar os posts.
Tentei puxar via RSS, porém, não consegui trazer as imagens dos thumbs dos posts.
É possível trazer tanto o conteúdo quanto a imagem thumb?
Poderiam me sugerir uma alternativa ao RSS, ou então, uma forma de puxar conteúdo e foto usando RSS?

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que terá que implementar uma "API" no site que deseja puxar as hospedagens. Tem disponibilidade para isso?

Comment: Então, eu consigo acessar os arquivos deste outro site.. Como seria esta api?

Comment: Não trabalho com wordpress, mas você teria que criar algum tipo de plugin para pegar os posts e fornece-los através de um json por alguma URL específica (http://minhaurl.com/posts.json), não se esqueça de autenticar/ou não de acordo com a sua necessidade.